# How to find out the size of an array when it is passed as an argument for the function?

Tags: c

I am passing one dimensional array as an argument for the function.How to find out the size of array in called function?

Below is the sample code :

```
# include<stdio.h>

int test( int array[ ] ) {
    //find the size of an array
}

int main() {

    int array[ ] = { 1,2,3,4};
    test( array );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/arrays/sizeof-array/

Comment: You can, of course, take your examples from the C standard library.  C-string oriented functions don't typically need to pass a length, because strings are null terminated.  Other "array" functions require a parameter passing the size or length.  That's how C's library functions do it.  You can do the same.

Comment: You need to pass an additional parameter to the `test` function because the array is treated as a pointer inside of a function, so you can't use `sizeof(array)` inside the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays decays into pointers when you pass to a function. With pointer alone, you can not get the size of the array. You have to pass one more argument to the calling function which is the size of the array.
Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test(int myArray[10], int size)
{
    printf("Size of myArray = %d\n", size);
}
void fun(int myArray[10])
{
    int i = sizeof(myArray);
    printf("Size of myArray = %d\n", i);
}
// This function prints the output 4 
int main(void)
{
    int myArray[10] = {0}; 
    fun(myArray);
    test(myArray, sizeof(myArray));
    getchar();            ^----------------Here you are passing the size
    return 0;
}
```

This would print the output 40 (Assuming the `sizeof int` is 4 on the platform)

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

```
int len_array1(int array[], int n) {
  return n;
}

int len_array2(int array[]) {
  int i;
  for(i=0;array[i]!=-1;++i) {}
  return i;
}

int main() {
  int array1[] = {1,2,3,4};
  int array2[] = {1,2,3,4,-1};

  operate_on_array1(array1,4);
  operate_on_array2(array2);
}
```

You can either store the length of the array somehow (or keep a point to its end) and pass that around, or you can include a special value at the end of the array which it would not otherwise appear in the values within the array.

Many C-style functions prefer the first option (`len_array1`), but C-style strings use the second option (the special value being the `0x00` or `\0` character).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in **C** as in **Java**,etc., but one alternative would be to send an `END` marking character, say, `0xFFFF` so that you can stop reading the data once it is found.

This would of course only be a work around and may only be used in such cases were you are absolutely certain that that data will not occur else.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are three ways :-

1)End-marking character:- This way is only useful, when you can be extremely sure that the character will not occur anywhere in the array passed as arguement.

2)Use a pointer always pointing to the end of the array:-
Now suppose, the end pointer is `ptr_end`, then you can calculate the difference b/w the addresses pointed to by the two pointers(one is the end pointer and the other is the name of the array), divide it by `sizeof(int)`, if you store int variable in the array:-

3)Pass `sizeof(array)` as the second arguement to the function. as demonstrated by another answer.

In your case, it seems that 1st and the 3rd ways are easy to implement  than the 2nd one.